# Access visible posts ONLY with facebook graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, posts

I am new to facebook graph. I manage to access all the posts using:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/THEPAGE/posts?access_token=MYTOKEN
```

But this list all posts. How to get visible posts only? Or how to determine if post is hidden on the page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you've requested the `read_stream` permission, every post object will include a [`privacy` field](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/privacy-parameter/) which specifies who can view that post. You can filter the posts on the client based on this field.

You're probably only interested in the `value` field of the privacy specification, which is one of `EVERYONE`, `ALL_FRIENDS`, `FRIENDS_OF_FRIENDS`, `CUSTOM`, or `SELF`. For example, posts which are visible to everyone will have `{"value":"EVERYONE"}` in the privacy field.

Comment: Thanks, how can I set this value from inside Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

There is a parameter include_hidden that you can send on each request:

> `https://graph.facebook.com/THEPAGE/posts?include_hidden=false&access_token=MYTOKEN`

Comment: The `include_hidden` parameter includes posts which have been *hidden* from a user's timeline or a page; it doesn't inspect the privacy of posts. Also, the default is false, so it won't change what the OP is seeing.